# Homogenous different equation solved correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Do I solve this homogeneous differential equation correctly? Thank you.

$$(2x^3 +y^3)dx -3xy^2dy =0$$

**Page $\boldsymbol 1$:**
\begin{align}
-3xy^2dy &= -(2x^3 +y^3)dx \\
 3xy^2dy &=  (2x^3 +y^3)dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{2x^3 +y^3}{3xy^2} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{2 +\dfrac{y^3}{x^3}}{3\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}} \quad(\text{divided by }x^3)\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{2 +\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^3}{3\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2}
\end{align}

Let $p=y/x$ so that $y=px$ and $y'=p'x+p$. Then,

\begin{align}
p'x +p &= \frac{2+p^3}{3p^2} \\
p'x &= \frac{2+p^3}{3p^2} -p \\
p'x &= \frac{2+p^3-3p^3}{3p^2} = \frac{2-2p^3}{3p^2} \\
\frac{dp}{dx} \cdot x &= \frac{2-2p^3}{3p^2} \\
\int \frac{3p^2}{2-2p^3} dp &= \int \frac{dx}{x}
\end{align}

**Page $\boldsymbol 2$:**
\begin{align}
-\frac12 \ln |2-2p^3| &= \ln|x| +c \\
\ln |2-2p^3|^{-1/2} &= \ln|x| +c \\
(2-2p^3)^{-1/2} &= x +c \\
\left(2-2\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3\right)^{-1/2} &= x \\
2^{-1/2} -\left(\frac{2y^3}{x^3}\right)^{-1/2} &= x +c \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} -\frac{2y^{-3/2}}{x^{-3/2}}} &= x +c \\
-\frac{2y^{-3/2}}{x^{-3/2}} &= x -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +c \\
-2y^{-3/2} &= x^{-3/2} \left(x -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +c\right) \\
y^{-3/2} &= \frac{x^{-3/2} \left(x -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +c\right)}{-2} \\
(y^{-3/2})^{(-2)} &= \left(\frac{x^{-3/2} \left(x -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +c\right)}{-2}\right)^{-2} \\
y^3 &= \left(\frac{x^{-3/2} \left(x -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +c\right)}{-2}\right)^{-2}
\end{align}

Comment: Now you have to write the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your first page is correct. However, your second page has a mistake, since $(a+b)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \neq a^{-\frac{1}{2}}+b^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Also, I suggest in the future that you simplify arbitrary constants when possible by defining new constants as I have done on my solution below.

Hence, I suggest you do the following:

We start from the point where I believe there are no errors.
$$-\frac{1}{2} \ln{|2-2p^3|}=\ln{|x|}+C$$
$$\ln{|2-2p^3|}^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\ln{|x|}+C$$

Exponentiating both sides:
$$e^{\ln{|2-2p^3|}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}=e^{\ln{|x|}+C}$$

$$(2-2p^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=e^{\ln{|x|}}\cdot e^C$$

We let $e^C=k$. This is ok to do, since $C$ is an arbitrary constant, hence $k$ will also be arbitrary.

$$(2-2p^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=kx$$

$$2-2p^3=(kx)^{-2}$$

Factorising:

$$2(1-p^3)=\frac{1}{(kx)^2}$$

$$1-p^3=\frac{1}{2(kx)^2}$$

$$p^3=1-\frac{1}{2(kx)^2}$$

$$p^3=\frac{2(kx)^2-1}{2(kx)^2}$$

$$p^3=\frac{2k^2 x^2-1}{2k^2 x^2}$$

Let $k_1=2k^2$

$$p^3=\frac{k_1 x^2-1}{k_1 x^2}$$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $k_1$:

$$p^3=\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{k_1}}{x^2}$$

Let $k_2=-\frac{1}{k_1}$

Substitute $p=\frac{y}{x}$

$$\frac{y^3}{x^3}=\frac{x^2+k_2}{x^2}$$

$$y^3=x^3+k_2 x$$

$$y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+k_2 x}$$

Hence, the general solution to our differential equation is:

$$y(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{x^2+k_2}$$

Where $k_2$ is an arbitrary constant.

Please do not hesitate to ask if you have any doubts or questions.